# Pass array and receive array in Promise.all

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list of currencies:

```
ETH: 0,
BTC: 0,
USD: 0,
UAH: 0,
EUR: 0,
```

Full code:

```js
data() {
    return {
      selected: 'USD',
      selected2: '',
      tickers: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'USD'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'EUR'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'UAH'
        },
      ],
      ETH: 0,
      BTC: 0,
      USD: 0,
      UAH: 0,
      EUR: 0,
      result: null,
      value: 1,
      modalOpened: false,
      tickersNew: null,
      currency: null,
    }
```

Get values for these currencies:

```js
async onChange() {
      const [result, ETH, BTC, USD, EUR, UAH] = await Promise.all([
        this.getValue(),
        this.getValue('ETH'),
        this.getValue('BTC'),
        this.getValue('USD'),
        this.getValue('EUR'),
        this.getValue('UAH'),
      ])
      this.result = result;
      this.ETH = ETH;
      this.BTC = BTC;
      this.USD = USD;
      this.EUR = EUR;
      this.UAH = UAH;
    },

    async getValue(selectedTo = this.selected2) {
      const API_KEY = 'API KEY HERE';
      const loadTicker = () =>
          fetch(
              `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=${this.selected}&tsyms=${selectedTo}&api_key=${API_KEY}`
          ).then(r => r.json()).then(r => r[selectedTo]);
      return (await loadTicker())
    },
```

How can I make the currency values ​​be in an array - ['ETH', 'BTC', 'USD', 'EUR', 'UAH']
So that I can add data to the array and get the result in the array. Thank you.

Comment: current code looks good. you must be getting all the values in your ETH, BTC etc variable. What is the issue?

Comment: Please remove your API key ser

Comment: `[{"USD":1},{"ETH":0.0006141},{"BTC":0.00004276},{"USD":1},{"EUR":0.9443},{"UAH":38.99}]
`
if this is what you wanted use spread `const [...res] = await Promise.all([
      ...
    `

Comment: The key inserted are not real. Yes, I need something similar. I will test.

Answer (score 2):

With this, you can add more tickers in the coins object and onChange will handle them

```
data() {
  return {
    coins: {result: 0, ETH: 0, BTC: 0, USD: 0, UAH: 0, EUR: 0}
  }
},
async onChange() {
      const coins = Object.keys(this.coins)
      const result = await Promise.all(coins.map(str => this.getValue(str === 'result' ? '' : str)))
      coins.forEach((str, idx) => { this.$set(this.$data.coins, str, result[idx]) })
},
```

Comment: It looks good. And how can I write / store values in DATA (data in the form of an array of objects)?   Now it looks like this, but we need an array of objects.                                                                  ETH: 0,
      BTC: 0,
      USD: 0,
      UAH: 0,
      EUR: 0,

Comment: Instead of having them as an array of objects, store them in an object in data, like `{ETH: 0, BTC: 0, USD: 0, UAH: 0, EUR: 0}`

Answer (score 0):

//an example (out of any framework)

```
let cids = ['ETH', 'BTC', 'USD', 'EUR', 'UAH']

function getCurrencies(arr) {
    let values = []
    values.push(getValue(arr[c])
    return values
}

Promise.all(getCurrencies(cids)).then((promises) => {
let cc
for (cc=0; cc<promises.length; cc++) {
    let r = promises[cc].value
    // in r is value resolved each promise
    // 

})
```